# Two-digit year format for localized formats in Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Is there a way in Moment.js to obtain a short year format (two digits only) for a localized date ?

```
moment().format('l'); // 1/23/2017

moment().format('<someSpecialFormat>'); // expected: 1/23/17
```

Any help or link to a related topic would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't expect to know what a user expects to see for date formats. Far better to use an unambiguous format that uses the month name, perhaps allowing the user to select the language so for French, you might use 1-jan-2017 or 1 janvier, 2017.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('L');
var formatYearlessL = formatL.replace(/YYYY/g,'YY');
console.log(moment().format(formatYearlessL));
```

Answer (score -2):

moment(/*Date Object*/).format('MM/DD/YY');

Comment: Thanks for answering, the problem with this approach is that it is not localized. For example, in french, the day is displayed before the month and forcing the format to MM/DD/YY goes against the principle of localized dates...